# Overloading << operator to print first n values of vector ( not whole vector )

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Below code can be used to print vector contents

```
template <class T>
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const vector<T> & data)
{ 
    out << "["; 
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) data.size(); ++i) 
        out << data[i] << (i == data.size() - 1 ? "" : ","); 
    out << "]"; 
    return out; 
}
```

Question:
1) If vector size is 5000 and only first n ( say 10 ) elements are storing values and others are not used then how to modify this code to print only first n values ?

2) I tried to print 2d vector as -

```
template <class T>
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const vector<vector<T>> & data)
{ 
    out << "["; 
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) data.size(); ++i)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < (int) data[i].size(); ++j )
            out << data[i][j] << (j == data[i].size() - 1 ? "" : ","); 
        out << endl;
    }
    out << "]"; 
    return out; 
}
```

but this does not work. So what is the proper way to print 1) whole 2d vector  ? and 2) some n * m values ( not whole 2d vector as asked in the first question for 1d vector ) ?

Comment: If the size of the vector is 5000, then the vector is storing 5000 values. There is no concept of non-values in a vector.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley - in competitive programming when there are more test cases then we are used to declare global vector of maximum input size but in most of the test cases whole vector is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventionally, `operator<<()` for streaming is implemented to output all of the data necessary to recreate the complete object, so `operator>>()` is able to reconstruct a copy of the object when, subsequently, reading from the stream.

A vector does not have a notion of "unused" values, unless its elements do.  For example, for a `std::vector<SomeType *>` it would be possible to output all the non-NULL elements.

If you want to output a specified number of elements of a `std::vector<std::vector<T> >` while discarding elements with a particular value, then implement a function to do that, for example;

```
 template<template <class T>
    std::ostream & OutputSubset (std::ostream & out, const vector<vector<T> > & data, std::size_t number, T discard)
  {
      if (number > data.size()) number = data.size();
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < number; ++i)
      {
          for (std::size_t j = 0; j < number; ++j)
              if (data[i][j] != discard) out << ' ' << data[i][j];
          out << '\n'; 
      }
      return out;
  }
```

Comment: "Not working" is an unspecific description.   I am not a mindreader, and the code here was written to demonstrate the approach (i.e. use a different function than `operator<<()`) not be a drop-in solution to your unspecified code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> values = ...
std::cout << head(values, 10) << '\n';
```

If you implement the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct HeadPrinter
{
  HeadPrinter(const T& container, size_t count)
    : _container(container), _count(count) {}

  const T& _container;
  size_t _count;
};

template <typename T>
HeadPrinter<T> head(const T& container, size_t count)
{
  return HeadPrinter<T>(container, count);
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const HeadPrinter<T>& printer)
{
  size_t count = std::min(printer._count, printer._container.size());
  out << '[';
  for (size_t ii = 0; ii < count; ++i) {
    out << printer._container[ii];
    if (ii + 1 < count) {
      out << ',';
    }
  }
  return out << ']';
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! but what to do for 2d vector ?

Comment: @knock_out: One question per question please.   Maybe post your second question as a new question.